Huggingface evaluate with f2
Is there a way to calculate f2 using huggingface's evaluate library?
ChatGPT instructed me to implement:
f2_metric = evaluate.load("f1", beta=2) 
However, the output was identical to that of the f1 metric, so I wasn't sure if the score was being calculated properly. Thank you so much!
